# CORS with Azure function from localhost (not CLI)

Tags: azure, cors, azure-functions, axios

We are using axios in a vue.js app to access an Azure function.  Right now we are getting this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

We are trying to set response headers in the function this way:

```js
context.res = {
  body: response.data,
  headers: {   
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'X-Custom-Header'
  }
}
```

Has anyone run across this error?

Comment: is CORS enabled on the server hosting your api code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  We are using Azure functions, so we don't configure the server.

Comment: so the resource that you are requesting from Azure is not configured with this header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". So for example, if that header was set by the server like this "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": www.google.com it would mean that that azure function allows request to come from google.

Comment: You should read about CORS requests. Basically, when the browser sees that the domains are different, it make a seperate call to the requested domain to get the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers to see what external domains are allowed access to the server. If the domain you are requesting FROM is not listed in the headers, then the browser does not allow the request to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried enabling CORS via the [Function App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#cors)?

Answer (score 140):

To set CORS working locally when you are not using CLI and you are using Visual Studio/ VS Code - you need to add local.settings.json file into your project if it's not there.

Make sure "Copy to output directly" set to "copy if newer"

[image: local.settings.json settings]

Then in your "local.settings.json" you can add `CORS": "*"` like so:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {

  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

Comment: This is not working. The default VS Azure Function template already has this file and CORS set to *. But if you try to access the localhost API from another website running localhost (but different port) it will not work.

Comment: This worked for me. Adding the CORS to local.settings.json fixed the network error I was getting in the browser. Removing the CORS and testing again caused the error to return.

Comment: This doesn't work with function runtime v4

Comment: This answer still works for azure function v4 in .NET 8.

Answer (score 51):

For `v3+` the following works:

p.s. note that location of `Hosts` is on the same level as `Values` and not under it (as in the answer by azadeh-khojandi https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069299/2705777)

Configure CORS in the local settings file `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "Values": {
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

We got it working.  It was a configuration in our Azure function.  You go to "Platform Features" then "CORS".  We added http://localhost:8080 to the list of "Allowed Origins" and then everything worked.

#### Elaboration For Production Environment Issues

I was having a problem on localhost, and on production (firebase hosted), trying to get my JavaScript Web app to interact with an Azure Function.

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (**CORS**) allows JavaScript code running in a browser on an external host to interact with your backend.

In Azure Functions, click the **features** tab, and click the **CORS** block under "networking and security".

Add your domain as an allowed origin and hit save. This will fix the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure this is very safe. Anybody could be running an application hosted locally on port 8080.

Comment: The question was about localhost. I got the same error and it's not even published to Azure yet.

Answer (score 21):

Had same problem. On root of backend project, there's a file local.settings.json.

Added "CORS": "*" and "CORSCredentials": false in that file (following is the example), did `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true` on root, and `mvn azure-functions:run -DenableDebug` on the azure function directory.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "<language worker>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connection-string>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<connection-string>",
    "MyBindingConnection": "<binding-connection-string>"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "<sqlclient-connection-string>"
  }
}
```

Reference:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=macos

Answer (score 14):

For those of you who are doing all of the above, but still not getting anything to work, it could be that your `local.settings.json` file is completely ignored. I don't know if this is because I'm using v3.

Go to Properties of your Project -> Debug -> Application arguments ->

```
host start --build --port 7071 --cors * --pause-on-error
```

Start your application

Comment: You are super life saver

Comment: `--cors *` didn't work for me. However `--cors http://localhost:8080` did. Using Python Azure funcs v3.

Answer (score 7):

You can enable the CORS from hosted environment in function app to add the web app URL  refer the below screenshot.

Enable CORS in Function app

[image: 1]

Note: TO allow all mark as "*"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the culprit was actually a typo in the Blazor-embedded-URI which Firefox displayed as a CORS error. Solution was just to realize that it had nothing to do with CORS and fix the mis-typed URI.

Comment: We also get very similar error in case the host is "not available". In my case the Azure Function Application was stopped and I got the following error message: `"origin 'https://REMOVED.core.windows.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."`

Answer (score 1):

Please note that CORS policies should be activated on the server where the resource is hosted.

In my case, despite I was testing my API in local, I was accessing a resource on the real blob storage, where no CORS policy was set.

**Activating the CORS policy on the blob storage** solved the issue, in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We had multiple CORS policies enabled and it didn't work. When we deleted every CORS policy and left only "*" (allow all) - it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you all guys are rocking....
Lesson is simple, to work Az function locally You must have local.settings.json otherwise it needs lot of unnecessary time-wasting changes
[image]