# CORS issue Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger on dev machine

Tags: reactjs, cors, azure-functions

I am currently working on a React SPA which is going to retrieve data from an HTTP-triggered Azure Functions. When running on my dev machine I am having issues with CORS and I'm not sure how to remedy that. I do so in the Azure Portal where there are options to enable CORS but I'm not sure how to replicate those locally.

Code:

```
const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:7071/api/jobs', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
```

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7071/api/jobs' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've already attempted to follow the following steps to add the CORS headers in .vs/--project--/config/applicationhost.config, but it did not fix the problem: https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/cors-development-in-localhost

Comment: Check if this SO post is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767255/cors-with-azure-function-from-localhost-not-cli

Comment: @MohsinMehmood That was the answer. Thank you!