# How to configure CORS in Azure function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have my Azure function which is running locally, I am looking for a way where I can set CORS in my local.

I went through the below Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#manage-cors) but couldn't able to achieve it.

Comment: Hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767255/cors-with-azure-function-from-localhost-not-cli

Answer (score 6):

**To Enable CORS in your function app running locally in your machine**

open the `local.settings.json` file (or create one if it doesn't exist. [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#local-settings)) in your function app root folder.

Then add (or append) the following to allow all :

```
{
    //Your other configs here
    "Host": {
        "CORS": "*"
    }
}
```

Or if you have a specific URL & port you want to whitelist

```
{
    //Your other configs here
    "Host": {
        "CORS": "http://localhost:12345"
    }
}
```

**To Enable CORS in your function app hosted in Azure :**

Go to your function app instance via the azure portal, then click on the "CORS" left menu option under the API section.

You can configure CORS for your function app here.

[image]

Azure docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#cors

Comment: So it has to be done via Azure Portal? No way of doing it in configuration files or startup class?

Comment: You can also set up your CORS policies using terraform (see : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_function_app) or azure CLI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/cors?view=azure-cli-latest). Also if you are using dotnet core func apps, maybe you can try to set it using the CORS middleware, though I haven't tried it myself so I can't say for sure that this will work (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I decided to use azure cli in PowerShell, it workes ok. Here I don't need to change code behind, can use pipeline variables, can reuse script and potentially expand azure cli commands for other pipeline stuff.